# Python fcntl.ioctl [Errno 1] Operation not permitted

Tags: python, raspbian, ioctl

I'm trying to run a python program using bluetooth_utils.py to read Bluetooth advertisements from a temperature/humidity device. It works fine when ran with root privileges (sudo) but can't cet it to run with a normal user (pi on a Raspberry in this case). I tried to isolate the faulting statement from my program and Library with these line of code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import sys
import struct
import fcntl
import array
import socket
from errno import EALREADY
import bluetooth._bluetooth as bluez
from bluetooth_utils import (toggle_device, enable_le_scan,
                             parse_le_advertising_events,
                             disable_le_scan, raw_packet_to_str)
dev_id = 0
enable = True
hci_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.BTPROTO_HCI)
print("Power %s bluetooth device %d" % ('ON' if enable else 'OFF', dev_id))
req_str = struct.pack("H", dev_id)
request = array.array("b", req_str)
hci_sock.fileno()
bluez.HCIDEVUP
bluez.HCIDEVDOWN
fcntl.ioctl(hci_sock.fileno(), bluez.HCIDEVUP if enable else bluez.HCIDEVDOWN, request[0])
toggle_device(dev_id, False)
```

The following is the result when ran with pi (Just copied/pasted in the interpretor):

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python
Python 2.7.16 (default, Oct 10 2019, 22:02:15) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from __future__ import absolute_import
>>> import sys
>>> import struct
>>> import fcntl
>>> import array
>>> import socket
>>> from errno import EALREADY
>>> import bluetooth._bluetooth as bluez
>>> from bluetooth_utils import (toggle_device, enable_le_scan,
...                              parse_le_advertising_events,
...                              disable_le_scan, raw_packet_to_str)
>>> dev_id = 0
>>> enable = True
>>> hci_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.BTPROTO_HCI)
>>> print("Power %s bluetooth device %d" % ('ON' if enable else 'OFF', dev_id))
Power ON bluetooth device 0
>>> req_str = struct.pack("H", dev_id)
>>> request = array.array("b", req_str)
>>> hci_sock.fileno()
3
>>> bluez.HCIDEVUP
1074022601
>>> bluez.HCIDEVDOWN
1074022602
>>> fcntl.ioctl(hci_sock.fileno(), bluez.HCIDEVUP if enable else bluez.HCIDEVDOWN, request[0])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
>>>
```

When I run the program with sudo (sudo python), it works fine.

```
>>> from __future__ import absolute_import
>>> import sys
>>> import struct
>>> import fcntl
>>> import array
>>> import socket
>>> from errno import EALREADY
>>> import bluetooth._bluetooth as bluez
>>> from bluetooth_utils import (toggle_device, enable_le_scan,
...                              parse_le_advertising_events,
...                              disable_le_scan, raw_packet_to_str)
>>> dev_id = 0
>>> enable = True
>>> hci_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.BTPROTO_HCI)
>>> print("Power %s bluetooth device %d" % ('ON' if enable else 'OFF', dev_id))
Power ON bluetooth device 0
>>> req_str = struct.pack("H", dev_id)
>>> request = array.array("b", req_str)
>>> hci_sock.fileno()
3
>>> bluez.HCIDEVUP
1074022601
>>> bluez.HCIDEVDOWN
1074022602
>>> fcntl.ioctl(hci_sock.fileno(), bluez.HCIDEVUP if enable else bluez.HCIDEVDOWN, request[0])
0
>>> toggle_device(dev_id, False)
Power OFF bluetooth device 0
>>>
```

Tried to find something about underlying authorities on some resources and couldn't find anything other than a communication port such as console...

Thanks very much for your help.

Daniel.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I believe I found a work around to this issue:

```
$ sudo setcap cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin+eip $(eval readlink -f `which python3`)
```

It does the trick by providing extra authorities (specific to network related things) to the python3 executable. I will also need to re-apply this command everytime I update the python3 executable.
Additional info about this command:

```
$ man setcap
$ man capabilities
```

At least, it allows me to move forward...